# transform interface such that ocurrences of a type are replaced by another type typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that traverses a given generic object (of type T) and then transforms certain props of a type to a different type. I need this function to also update the input type (T) to reflect the changes in the typing done by the function.

I'm trying to accomplish the following: given `Interface1`:

```
interface Interface1 {
  prop1: Type1
  prop2: Type2
  prop3: {
    subprop1: Type1
    subprop2: Type2
  }
}
```

then I need a type expression like `Transform<T>` such that doing `Transform<Interface1>` results in:

```
interface Interface2 {
  prop1: NewType
  prop2: Type2
  prop3: {
    subprop1: NewType
    subprop2: Type2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done - but at what cost?

It might be worth trying to see if there's a way you can do what you want to do in a simpler manner. There's not a lot of context so I can't advise on how you would approach this - I usually try and stay away from stuff like this for maintainability reasons.

This will do what you're asking - where T is the object type to transform, TTarget is Type1 and TResult is NewType

First - the simpler form which lazily evaluates. This means you get the following output when hovering over the result type:

[image]

```
type Transform1<T extends object, TTarget, TReplacement> = {
    [key in keyof T]:
        T[key] extends object
            ? Transform1<T[key], TTarget, TReplacement>
            : T[key] extends TTarget ? TReplacement : T[key];
}
```

This version will eagerly evaluate the nested object - giving you more 'correct' looking type hints

[image]

```
type Transform2<T extends object, TTarget, TReplacement> = {
    [key in keyof T]:
        T[key] extends object
            ? {
                [innerKey in keyof Transform2<T[key], TTarget, TReplacement>]:
                    Transform2<T[key], TTarget, TReplacement>[innerKey]
              }
            : T[key] extends TTarget ? TReplacement : T[key];
}
```

How this works is that we first map over T using a mapped type -

```
{ [key in keyof T]: T[key] }
```

Next we need to check if T[key] is a nested object, and if so - we need to recurse the type. We do this by asking if `T[key] extends object`. If it does, `Transform<T[key], TTarget, TResult>` again.

Then we can check if T[key] is assignable to the TTarget we are trying to replace with `T[key] extends TTarget`. If it does, return TReplacement, otherwise leave it alone by returning T[key].

The eagerly evaluated version just uses a little trick where we map over the result type again.

We are doing the same `{[key in T]: T[key]}` - except we replace T with the thing we want to evaluate - which is `Transform<T[key], TTarget, TResult>`. We also need another variable for key, because we're now mapping over the inner type, so I used innerKey here.

This gives us

```
{ [innerKey in keyof Transform2<T[key], TTarget, TReplacement>]: Transform2<T[key], TTarget, TReplacement>[innerKey] }
```

Playground link:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEYoF4oGdgCcCWA7A5gNwBQoks8ATClAEYD29ANhAIa4lnQByEA7nHKpcAVwC2tCJhLE8wKQDNWAY2gBJXPMxLVSAN7EoUMJnpgEALgqQEh46bCUrgiJTsmzAZisGjRtCK0HubO8LZ+6IHBTtaudgC+xImymooq6qna6dS+9maWULwC8O4OMS5uRsHeULn+UQ4FRS529UFloZCVUInJAPR9sAAW2GhQfNhMTFBMrABekyBQEABurEwirPJQwEPQuBAYEAAmUPS0AFYQysCk8LCY7GgK9JhiCAA8MMsAHvK4xzG5yuNwANLAYKxMPgIMBwTAAEoQMCzVRiCCaAB8NDqUAA2gBrCBLPBQIkgegKWAAXQsrQisEJxOpv3+gLOl2utwZPKgAH4Hk8Xm9PjAmSBqfDIdDYfCkSj0uisfTeVBnOKWRA-hj2TBpTDgPzYPLURAlYb1eTqSR4lBiMQBsNRuNJtM2DDMEwlqt1pttrt9od5KdgVyoABaKD4bArPD4KAUkRQMSvaAAcmUr0wXLTM0YBLjO3uI00aDu5Bgj1wz1eYkoX1ZOqBnLBEKhBrlyNN5uxqFx4qgpPJlJpdNVYqtjYBzZB3NVfgFuPnfjxeAOmAA0sTB7gycSR5WhbX6xPmVL27LjV3FRjgJjaSrlwzD9XhXWvhrzzK4VeFWjb5iq64OuW4So+qqJE+aqMpOWpsmMeoXoaAqIte-6aNBp4Sjadr2o6AAS9ArFIZzEZgUBIgETDAEgwD0OgEDQFwUAlrczGUSI1FIKgL41iKHwaFoOiIPCYTgs08CYjIBFESRsnkRx1HUHRDFMcWcjltAinANQPFVnx76CWkuiiTY4n8C4UlAA

Answer (score 0):

i would propose something like this:

```
type Rep<T, R, Target> = Target extends T 
  ? R 
  : Target extends Object 
    ? { [K in keyof Target]: Rep<T, R, Target[K]> } 
    : Target extends infer X 
      ? X 
      : never
```

for example for:

```
interface Interface1 {
  prop1: number
  prop2: string
  prop3: {
    subprop1: string
    subprop2: {
        subprop2_1: number,
        subpeop2_2: {
            subprop2_2_1: number
        }
    }
    subprop3 : number
  }
}
```

replacing all `number`s with `{x: string}` could look like this:

```
type T1 = Rep<number, { x: string }, Interface1>
```

producing this type signature:

```
type T1 = {
  prop1: {
    x: string;
  };
  prop2: string;
  prop3: {
    subprop1: string;
    subprop2: {
      subprop2_1: {
        x: string;
      };
      subpeop2_2: {
        subprop2_2_1: {
          x: string;
        };
      };
    };
    subprop3: {
      x: string;
    };
  };
}
```

[tsplayground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShYB4AqAaWakEMBOBzCwAfFALxRZ4FQQAewEAdgCYDO5UAUFFAPyyfcAXORz5g1Oo1ZQA8gCMAVhADG4rt15QA3lADaAaSgBLBlADWEEAHsAZiMrAAusLiJU6e2IOPiAXwEawhRiEvTMbCY2ENhQABoBGprx6onCDBAAbtEcHCb02DaYytAAkgz5hcUAjNrqYNhWYFVpAK4AtnLZ3PWNAEzCLMDYJrh1DWAAzMJaKVAsLXI9TQNDI7Pzi+P9tYmJG0u9APrNUAztndgos3sLkH2H2zO7z3O3Ww-HrR1dL76zfzdNo0JlAvhd1H8-hxQJByDUyK4EGdvpdtFAaCthgxcFBfGgyhUihAqoQgA)